# How to fix eslint error import/no-extraneous-dependencies for Strapi plugin?

Tags: eslint, strapi, eslintrc

Strapi's plugins have its own package.json and own unique dependencies. But also plugin is provided by all packages from Strapi itself (those packages are listed in core package.json of Strapi project). Eslint doesn't understand that. How to fix?

That option didn't help (after applying all warning disappear and eslint stops working in vcs):

```
packageDir: path.join(__dirname, './src/plugins/pluginname'),
```